# Adding Library to Debug Config - QtCreator, VC Compiler

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, compilation, linker

After adding the libmusicxml library to my project in QtCreator (using the VC 2012 Compiler) the project will compile using the release configuration not however using the debug configuration. In the linking phase a number of build problems concering unresolved external symbols occur.

Having read through other posts I realise that I have to link to the library for both configurations separately. I have tried adding the following variants to my .pro-file without any success.

- ## 1

  LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/ -llibmusicxml2

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include

  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include`
- ## 2

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/ -llibmusicxml2

  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/ -llibmusicxml2d

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include

  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include
- ## 3, leaving out the d suffix in line 3

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/ -llibmusicxml2

  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/ -llibmusicxml2

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include

  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include

The error messages look like

main.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*thiscall MusicXML2::xmlreader::~xmlreader(void)" (*_imp_??1xmlreader@MusicXML2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

I hope somebody can help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In our projects we do it like this:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32
win32 {
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -llibmusicxml2d
    } else {
        LIBS += -llibmusicxml2
    }
}
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include

DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/libmusicxml-3.00-win32/include
```

Comment: the error I keep getting is "C1083: Can´t open "xml.h": no such file or directory (in debug mode only) - Thanks for the attempt

Comment: Do you still have the `INCLUDEPATH` and `DEPENDPATH` defined? I edited my answer to make it clear.